# ∴ [math] ≡ [mathematics]

Tags: discussion, tagging

The [math](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) should be merged into [mathematics](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematics), and a synonym relation set up, with [mathematics](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematics) as the canonical tag. Ideally, [maths](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maths) would also exist as a synonym.

Comment: Agreed, although, this can probably be handled by single user with full edit privilege - there are currently only 3 questions tagged `[math]` - retagging them to `[mathematics]` will be the simplest path.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There were only three questions tagged with [math](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math). I found that for two of them the tag was irrelevant, and the third one I changed to [mathematics](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematics). That will cause the system to delete the [math](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) tag, unless someone tags a questions with it in the next pass of the tag deleting job.

I haven't done anything about [maths](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maths), and I don't know if I can, but for now there are no questions with that tag.

Comment: Now all that needs to be done is to hunt down someone with at least 5 points in `mathematics` to propose the synonyms, and a few others to vote on them. Apparently I haven't ever even _answered_ a question about maths here, let alone received any votes on it.

Comment: @StarfishPrime I'm ready, waiting and unclear how to proceed. Just tried and received the dreaded: "Failed to propose synonym:The suggested tag must exist in the system before you propose it as a synonym" Has someone already helpfully (and sneakily) deleted it then?

Comment: Ditto for the [tag:maths] tag.

Comment: @WeareMonica. possibly you're in the wrong place? were you here? https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tags/mathematics/synonyms

Comment: @StarfishPrime Yes, is that bad? I was assuming it wasn't a meta-tag being discussed.

Comment: @WeareMonica. weird, seems like that should have worked. I'd try with some other tag that I have enough points to edit, only I'm hesitant to add testing-only synonyms and can't think of any real and useful ones. Maybe you do have to retag another question first to make your suggestion somehow real.

Comment: If it's no longer on any posts, it was probably auto-deleted, @WeareMonica.